# Removing blank lines from a textarea's output

Tags: php, regex, trim

I get data from a textarea where a user has to enter a name one on  each line. That data later gets split at the carriage return. Sometimes a user may add blank lines intentionally. How can I detect these lines and delete them? I'm using PHP. I dont mind using a regexp or anything else.

**Incorrect Data**

```
Matthew
Mark
Luke

John

James
```

**Correct Data (Note blank lines removed)**

```
Matthew
Mark
Luke
John
James
```

Comment: rtrim, trim, str_replace

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using regex to eliminate blank lines *before* exploding (works well for any number of consecutive blank lines, also see next snippet):

```
$text = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", trim($_POST['textarea']));
```

Splitting with a regex:

```
$lines = preg_split('/\n+/', trim($_POST['textarea']));
$text = implode("\n", $lines);
```

Splitting without a regex:

```
$lines = array_filter(explode("\n", trim($_POST['textarea'])));
$text = implode("\n", $lines);
```

Just feeling a tad creative today, pick your poison :)

Comment: Great answer. And since Norman needs the data as an array, `preg_split('/\n+/', trim($_POST['textarea']))` is all he needs.

Comment: @JoostK: Well, you're right. My code now separates `$lines` from `$text` appropriately so it's easier to follow.

Comment: Sorry, but the last code block wont work. We will be getting a `1 byte` space for empty lines, and hence `array_filter` wont cut it. Please correct it :)

Comment: `$lines = array_filter(array_map('trim',explode("\n",($_POST['textarea'])))); `that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple string replace should do the trick, I believe.

```
str_replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n", $text);
```

Comment: Doing this in a single pass will convert 3 newlines to 2, and so on. You could use `while (strpos($text, "\r\n\r\n") !== false)` to check.

Answer (score 0):

After splitting your input, loop the array searching for empty lines:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['your_textarea']);
foreach ($lines as $k=>$v) if(empty($v)) unset($lines[$k]);
```

You could even look for lines containing just spaces to also delete them:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['your_textarea']);
foreach ($lines as $k=>$v) if(empty(trim($v))) unset($lines[$k]);
```

(Both code snippets are untested)

NOTE: Be careful when splitting by line breaks (I splitted them by \n, but could be \r\n if the client browser runs on Windows).

Comment: `array_filter` does exactly what you're doing here.