# avoid blank lines in a textarea using php

Tags: php, html, textarea

I am using below php code to process two textareas called `namelist` and `placelist` and echo it to html.

```
<?php

$namelist = $_POST['namelist'];
$placelist = $_POST['placelist'];

$names = explode("\n", $namelist); 
$places = explode("\n", $placelist); 

$entries = min(count($names), count($places));

for ($i = 0; $i < $entries; $i++) {
$name  = trim($names[$i]); 
$place = trim($places[$i]);
echo "My name is $name and I am from $place ".PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

But above code processing the blank lines in my textareas ? I need to avoid blank lines from echoing.
for example, if the `namelist` contains

```
Tom
George
```

and `placelist` contains

```
GK
US
```

I will get output like:

```
My name is Tom and I am from GK 
My name is George and I am from US
```

But If there is a blank line in an of the textarea it processing the blank line too. eg:

```
Tom
George
```

and

```
GK

US
```

It will give below output like

```
My name is Tom and I am from GK 
My name is George and I am from
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214685/removing-blank-lines-from-a-textareas-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Using `regex` to eliminate blank lines before exploding (works well for any number of consecutive blank lines)

```
$name = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", trim($_POST['namelist']));
$place = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", trim($_POST['placelist']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the blank line from the array by the following code

```
$names = explode("\n", $namelist); 
$places = explode("\n", $placelist); 

foreach($names as $name)
{
$name=trim($name);
if($name!="")
{
$new_names[]=$name;
}
}

foreach($places as $place)
{
$place=trim($place);
if($place!="")
{
$new_places[]=$place;
}
}
```

Then you can use the two new array i.e $new_names and $new_places

Comment: What if I insert `\r` instead of `\n`